# Ask REST API for specific data and if satisfied with answer open django app url

Tags: angularjs, django, rest

What I want to achieve may be a bit of an overkill, but I want to check if that's even possible. I'm a newbie at angularjs.

How can I use angular, so:

1. Sends GET to REST API (let's say /product/)
2. If it receives specific value (let's say x > 0) it redirects to django app url (let's say /add/),
3. Else it may generate error (let's say ).

Comment: You can "redirect" in javascript simply by calling `location = '/add/'`

Comment: http://www.angulartutorial.net/2014/05/set-headers-for-all-http-calls-in.html
I hope this example will help